# De Moivre's Theorem for proving

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have been asked by my lecturer to answer this question but I'm having problems doing so.  The question is:

> Prove that
>
> $$\cos (5\theta) = 16\cos^5\theta - 20\cos^3\theta + 5 \cos\theta\text{.}$$

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091201092452AACP5VB

Comment: you have to prove this by Moivre?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$cos 5\theta = \Re (cos 5\theta + i sin 5\theta)$$

Using De Movire

$$=\Re \left( (cos \theta + i sin \theta)^5\right)$$

Now all you have to do is use binomial expansion and then removing the imaginary parts.

Comment: You also need to use that $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta=1$.

Comment: @Ihf , really ? How is that used in this question? Let me know im interested. I haven't ever used this identity in such problems

Comment: $\Re \big((\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^5\big)$ contains even powers of $\sin \theta$, doesn't it?

Comment: @TheArtist The formula is merely for converting $\sin\theta$ to $\cos\theta$. Since the question asks us for a formula in terms of $\cos\theta$ only, we'll have to use it since sines will appear in $(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^5$.

Comment: @mathh ohhhh i got it...yes have to use that , Im a tubelight. Got confused